# Displaying a triangle with Qt and OpenGL

Tags: qt, opengl

I am trying to display a triangle with OpenGL and Qt but only get a black window.
What am I doing wrong?

glwidget.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <QGLWidget>

class GLWidget : public QGLWidget {
public:
    GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
   ~GLWidget();
   QSize sizeHint() const {  return QSize(400, 400); }

protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int width, int height);
};
```

glwidget.cpp:

```
#include "glwidget.h"

GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) : QGLWidget(parent) {}

GLWidget::~GLWidget(){ }

void GLWidget::initializeGL() { }

void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(-1.5f,0.0f,-6.0f);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
     glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
     glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);
     glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnd(); 
}

void GLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    QGLWidget::resize(w,h);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "glwidget.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    GLWidget glWidget;
    glWidget.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must set a viewport and projection at the beginning of the paintGL member function. Put this at the beginning of your paintGL:

```
QSize viewport_size = size();
glViewport(0, 0, viewport_size.width(), viewport_size.height());

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glFrustum(-1, 1, -1, 1, 5, 7); // near and far match your triangle Z distance

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Also if the window is double buffered, the buffers must be swapped, after drawing. Either set

```
setAutoBufferSwap(true);
```

in the constructor, to swap after paintGL returns, or add

```
swapBuffers();
```

at the end of paintGL.

Comment: Thanks datenwolf! One thing I do not understand though; glFrustum has a distance from 5(near) to 7(far) from camera (z=0). However my triangle is located at z = -6!? I would think that my triangle should be located at z = 6, or is the convention in OpenGL negative z meaning into screen?

Comment: @Andy: The default convention of OpenGL is a depth range of [0…1], with GL_GREATER depth sorting. glFrustum maps cordinates into negative Z direction to positive depth values. Effectively this means that default OpenGL settings map negative Z values into the screen. Hence the near and far values of glFrustum are meant as distances into the negative Z direction.

Comment: @datenwolf: No, the default depth test use `GL_LESS`. The reason the Z is negative is because that's how OpenGL's perspective matrix works. -Z is in front of the camera, +Z is behind. The zNear and zFar are distances (and thus always positive), not camera-space values.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Err, of course it's GL_LESS, my bad. Far plane default is at 1, near at 0.

Answer (score -1):

triangle is transform out the form

```
glTranslatef(-0.5f,0.0f, 0.0f);

glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
 glVertex3f( 0.0f, 0.2f, 0.0f);
 glVertex3f(-0.2f,-0.2f, 0.0f);
 glVertex3f( 0.2f,-0.2f, 0.0f);
glEnd();
```