# Fail to generate a triangle by openGL with Qt5.0.2

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

OS : mac osx 10.8.3

---

compiler : clang3.2

---

I am a beginner of opengl, trying to play opengl with Qt5

There are two problems about this simple program(plot a triangle)

1. I can't see the triangle
2. The program could not exit even I close the window

hpp

```
#include <QGLWidget>

#include <QtGui/QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QtGui/QOpenGLShaderProgram>

class QWidget;

class ch1HelloTriangle : public QGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ch1HelloTriangle(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    virtual void initializeGL();
    void initShaders();
    void InitializeVertexBuffer();

    virtual void resizeGL(int w, int h);
    virtual void paintGL();

private:
    QOpenGLShaderProgram program;

    GLuint positionBufferObject;
};
```

.cpp

```
#include <locale.h>

#include <QWidget>

#include "ch1HelloTriangle.hpp"

namespace
{

float const vertexPositions[] = {
    0.75f,  0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
};

}

ch1HelloTriangle::ch1HelloTriangle(QWidget *parent) :
    QGLWidget(parent)
{
}

void ch1HelloTriangle::initializeGL()
{
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    InitializeVertexBuffer();
    initShaders();
}

void ch1HelloTriangle::initShaders()
{
    // Override system locale until shaders are compiled
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");

    // Compile vertex shader
    if (!program.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex,
                                         "attribute vec4 position;\n"
                                         "void main()\n"
                                         "{\n"
                                         "   gl_Position = position;\n"
                                         "}\n"))
    {
        close();
    }

    // Compile fragment shader
    if (!program.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment,
                                         "out vec4 outputColor;\n"
                                         "void main()\n"
                                         "{\n"
                                         "   outputColor = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);\n"
                                         "}\n"))
    {
        close();

    }

    // Link shader pipeline
    if (!program.link())
        close();

    // Bind shader pipeline for use
    if (!program.bind())
        close();

    // Restore system locale
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
}

void ch1HelloTriangle::InitializeVertexBuffer()
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &positionBufferObject);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferObject);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexPositions), vertexPositions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

void ch1HelloTriangle::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    // Set OpenGL viewport to cover whole widget
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

void ch1HelloTriangle::paintGL()
{        
     /*
     //codes propose by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111291/displaying-a-triangle-with-qt-and-opengl?rq=1, can't see the triangle either
     QSize viewport_size = size();
     glViewport(0, 0, viewport_size.width(), viewport_size.height());

     glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
     glLoadIdentity();
     glFrustum(-1, 1, -1, 1, 5, 7); // near and far match your triangle Z distance

     glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);*/

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferObject);

    int vertexLocation = program.attributeLocation("position");
    program.enableAttributeArray(vertexLocation);

    glVertexAttribPointer(vertexLocation, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);    
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>

#include "ch1HelloTriangle.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    ch1HelloTriangle ch1;
    ch1.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I see that you had code to set the projection matrix but removed it. Why? If you're using the fixed-function pipeline, that's probably why you aren't seeing the triangle. If you're not using the fixed-function pipeline, then please show your vertex shader, too.

Comment: I removed it because the results would be the same even I add those lines.Besides, the vertex shader and fragments shader are inside the function "initShaders".The function read the shaders from the source codes.

Comment: The answer to your second question lies in the first line of your post. You are on Mac OS, this is the way it works. Closing the window does not close the application, you need to use `Cmd+q` to close the application.

Comment: And for the first question, you need to multiply vertex coordinates by projection and model-view matrices in your vertex shader. I don't know how matrices are handled in Qt, but in pure OpenGL starting from version 3 you need to pass these matrices as uniforms to your vertex shader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I solved the problem.

Change two things :
1 : read the shader by files

```
// Compile vertex shader
    if (!program.addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, "modernOpenGLShader/ch1/vertex")){
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "QOpenGLShader::Vertex", "QOpenGLShader::Vertex" + program.log());
        close();      
    }

    // Compile fragment shader
    if (!program.addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, "modernOpenGLShader/ch1/frag")){
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "QOpenGLShader::Fragment", "QOpenGLShader::Fragment" + program.log());
        close();    
    }
```

2 : change the fragment shader, remove the output variable

```
void main() {
    //set every drawn pixel to white
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

From the websites, "modern opengl":http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/
and "another site":tomdalling.com/blog/modern-opengl/01-getting-started-in-xcode-and-visual-cpp/

The output qualify should exist(atleast the codes of the second website will work on my pc)
But Qt will throw error message

**QOpenGLShader::FragmentERROR: 0:4: Invalid qualifiers 'out' in global variable context**

Do anyone know why?Thanks